# Minimum version for syscall clone

Tags: linux-kernel, syscalls

Which was the first linux-kernel version to implement the system call clone? (sys_clone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offhand, the manual page implies 2.4, but [this page](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=2.0.40;i=sys_clone) says 2.0.40 had it.